# Waf - Source not found: None

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, 64-bit, waf

I'm trying to compile a 64-bit application using `Waf`, but the `wscript` is returning the error:

> `Source not found: None`.

I have heard that this can be due to improper indentation or mixed character encodings, which my `wscript` does not have.

Any possible solutions/leads to what may be causing this?

Comment: Changing the verbosity of the build (`waf build -v`, `-vv` or `-vvv`) may give you a hint about where in your script the problem is

Comment: Found the error! But just created my account and can't post the answer yet, so I'll post it here in the interim...

Originally for my sources I was using:
    bld.path.find_resource(file_name) for file_name in
Waf couldn't find one of the file paths I was giving it so the resource became None. This was solved by:
   file_name for file_name in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error!
Previously, for my sources I was using:

```
bld.path.find_resource(file_name) for file_name in
```

One of the file paths did not exist, so the resource became None.
Since I was using absolute file paths, I solved by changing to:

```
file_name for file_name in
```